# putting two JMenu's next eachother JAVA

Tags: java, swing, awt

I added two `JMenus` on a frame :

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//Menu :
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menu = new JMenu("Fichier");
menu2 = new JMenu("Options");
JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.addActionListener(MyListener);
menuBar.add(menu);
menuBar.add(sep);
menuBar.add(menu2);
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

This is the result I want :
[image]

This is the result I got :
[image]

Please give me any ideas on how this frame was made :
[image]

I tried doing this with a `JWindow` and adding a `JTextArea`, but it takes the size of the whole window and i can't even write on it.

Code for `JWindow`:

```java
public class Fenetre extends JWindow
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    JTextArea ta;

    Fenetre()
    {
        setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
        ta = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ta);
        add(ta);
        
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                X = e.getX();
                Y = e.getY();
            }
        });
        
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                Point p = getLocation();
                setLocation(p.x + (e.getX() - X), p.y + (e.getY() - Y));
            }
        });
        
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the separator

Comment: @MadProgrammer That did work thanks, can you help me with the second part of my question.

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer. The vertical separator is not really necessary. Unless you use some `LayoutManager` and add it to the `JMenuBar`, you will have that "weird" behavior. Basically, there is a way to do what you want, but the amount of effort it will take might not be worth it.

Comment: @hfontanez Oh I see, i'll just use **menu2 = new JMenu("Options      |");**, thanks !

Comment: Not sure why you need a `JWindow` personally, it wouldn't be my first choice, in fact, an undecorated `JFrame` would be a better place to start

Comment: @MAR1 I guess you can do that. I would just enter the text without the "|"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `JWindow` it has focus issues (actually I think it's by design, but I'm unfamiliar with the details)

Instead, simply make use of an undecorated window (assuming what you want is no window decorations)

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, if you "need" some padding around the edges, either use a layout manager that allows you to specify padding or use a `EmptyBorder`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
                frame.setContentPane(content);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think you will find:

- [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

a better place to start.

Also, in future, ask 1 specific question, otherwise you risk having the question closed for "needing more focus"

Answer (score 1):

Since the first part is already answered in the comments by MadProgrammer, I will focus on the second part. As I understand it, you want to place a text area in the frame that takes the entire space.

### Step 1: Create a content pane:

```
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea console = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(console);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

### Step 2: Add it to the frame

```
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
```

Because the are no other components added to the frame, the frame layout manager will allow this contentPane to "stretch out" and take the entire space.

When the frame first renders, you won't see the scroll bars. As you enter text into the text area, you will eventually see the scroll bars as the component gets filled with information. Alternatively, you can make the size of the text area larger (currently set to 5 x 30) than the size of the frame and you will see the scroll bars. For example, if you resize the frame manually to make it smaller than 5 rows (high) and 30 columns (wide), you will see the scroll bars render. Why I am saying this? So that you can decide what is the correct size you want the text area to be.